# terra interpolate output is a linear gradient instead of distribution points

Tags: r, terra, gstat

I am trying to model species distributions and I am using species presence data only. I would like to correct my models for sampling bias in the region. To achieve this, I fit a model using gstat and wanted to use terra::interpolate, to be able to weight down at the end my self-generated species absences in the places where there are few species surveys.
I expected my output at the end to display somehow the distribution of the amount of sampled species in a grid cell `(sum)`, and I was expecting to use this factor to weight down my absences, as explained above. My output is a linear gradient and I do not think that I am getting the output I need.

Here is a snippet of the data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(8.875, 8.875, 9.375, 9.625, 9.875, 10.125, 
6.125, 6.375, 6.625, 7.125, 7.375, 7.625, 8.875, 9.125, 9.375, 
9.625, 9.875, 10.125, 10.375, 10.875, 11.125, 2.875, 3.125, 3.375, 
3.625, 3.875, 4.125, 4.375, 4.625, 4.875), 
  y = c(37.625, 37.375, 
37.375, 37.375, 37.375, 37.375, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 
37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 
37.125, 37.125, 37.125, 36.875, 36.875, 36.875, 36.875, 36.875, 
36.875, 36.875, 36.875, 36.875), 
  sum = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 0, 2, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
```

Here is my code:

```
#Define the extent and resolution of the blank raster for interpolate
extent <- c(-25.36097, 51.4157, -46.9825, 37.55986)
cell_size <- c(0.25, 0.25)

#Create the blank raster with the specified extent and resolution
blankRaster <- rast(ext(extent), res=.25)
res(blankRaster) <- cell_size

# Fit the model. The "sum" of species in a cell is dependant of the coordinates, therefore sum~x+y
model <- gstat(id = "sum", formula = sum~x+y, locations = ~x+y, data =df)

#Interpolate results
interp <- terra::interpolate(blankRaster, model, xyNames = c("x", "y"))

plot(interp[[1]])
```

[image]

I tried fitting the model in different ways and using different maps when using terra::interpolate, but the output is always pretty similar.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The results seem reasonable given your data and choice of extent. That is easier to see with a smaller extent; and considering that all southern values are high, and the most northern values are low.

```
extent <- as.vector(apply(df[,1:2], 2, range))
b <- rast(ext(extent)+.5, res=.05)

model <- gstat(id = "sum", formula = sum~x+y, locations = ~x+y, data =df)
interp <- terra::interpolate(b, model, xyNames = c("x", "y"))
#[ordinary or weighted least squares prediction]
#[ordinary or weighted least squares prediction]


plot(interp[[1]])
text(df[,1:2], labels=df[,3], cex=.5)
```

[image]

Perhaps least squares interpolation is not what you are after. You could try

```
model <- gstat(id = "sum", formula =sum~1, locations = ~x+y, data =df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does look like this is not what I am looking for. Using `formula =sum~1` wouldn't be correct, I think, because I want to check for the dependency of my sum in relationship with my coordinates. I am kind of looking for a factor to be able to "dilute" my absences in grid with overall low amount of information.